# What is the URL to open a link in salesforce1 mobile app?

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have created a lightning component in salesforce1 for my project to scan the QR code and then redirect to the contact, based on the QR code. I have used Scan.me app for QR code capture. For some reason, the url directs to classic salesforce and I have to login everytime in browser and then it opens in salesforce1.

```
if (component.get("v.UrlType") == "Custom Field"){

        var callback = component.get("v.baseURL")
          + "/apex/BarCodeSearch?objectName="
          + component.get("v.CustomObject") 
          + "&fieldName="
          + component.get("v.CustomField")
          + "&fieldValue=SCANNED_DATA";

        var url = "scan://scan?callback=" + encodeURIComponent(callback);    
        urlEvent.setParams({
            "url": url
        });
    }
```

**BaseURL= https://coxauto--ssgph.lightning.force.com**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is you are testing on a mobile device. Have you tried to use force:navigate...? 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToComponent.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm

Reference from chat room: https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce1_url_schemes.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62832/discussion-between-chris-chen-and-user3303348).